# Nodejs express на Es6

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Можно ли писать апи приложение на nodejs express используя синтаксис es6? Я не смог даже файл заипортить с класом через import Class from './class'. Может нужно его транспилировать в ес5? Если да то как?

Comment: [Связанный вопрос на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37132031/2881286)

Answer (score 1):

Babel.js - переводит на старый стандарт

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать nodejs 10 версии с флагом `--experimental-modules` или  esm ([ссылка](https://github.com/standard-things/esm)) модулем. Все нововведения новых стандартов будут работать из коробки.

На текущий момент node 10 поддерживать почти весь основной набор улучшений современных стандартов es8
https://node.green/#ES2018